# No creation rule for font ""

Tags: fonts, miktex, compiling, source

I am receiving the following error message:

> Running miktex-makemf.exe...
>
> miktex-makemf: The source file could not be found. Running
>   hbf2gf.exe...
>
> hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0) `' can't be a subfont created by hbf2gf
>   miktex-maketfm
>
> : No creation rule for font ""

I have tried to tried to execute 'initexmf --update-fndb' and 'initexmf --mkmaps', but the error message remains. Can anyone help?

I suspect that is due to using package '\usepackage{pxfonts}'. A minimal working is extremely simple (see below). Reinstalling the package pxfonts also did not resolve the issue.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pxfonts} 
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `\pdfmapfile{=pdftex35.map}` to your document?

Comment: Try running `updmap --verbose` from the command line.

Comment: Please answer these questions: **1. Which LaTeX editor are you using?** 2. When you compiled your document, did you have internet connection? 3. Have you already tried fixing the issue with MikTeX Package Manager? On my system, TeXSudio simply asked if I want to install the mentioned package and then compiled just fine. I suspect that something is wrong with your installation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, your suggestion fixed the issue. Could you elaborate a bit on what the prolem was and how your recommendation solves it?